# Transfer function : Determination

Tags: circuit-analysis, transfer-function, formula-derivation, algorithm, nodal-analysis

I have the below circuit, here, I have Is and Va are measurable quantities. Rc1..Rc4 and Rbd are unknown variables for which I intend to derive transfer function. I have flexibility of adding additional resistances or switches in the circuit to get the equations. I am not sure how to go about it.
[image]

---

I am thinking of adding the switches S1,S2 and Sx, and resistance R1 to generate 5 equations for switch combinations S1,S2,Sx[000,100,010,101,011]
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127584/discussion-on-question-by-seeker-transfer-function-determination).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your effort to compensate the skin contact resistances is useless. The current source pushes the certain AC current through the tissue, no matter is the contact resistance =0 or more. The resistance between the driver probes must only be smaller than some specified maximum. The current spreads like tissues allow and you get some current density vector field and scalar potential field. Your BIP-BIN probes sample that potential field at two points. What they get doesn't at all depend on contact resistances of BIP-BIN probes as long as those resistances are below megaohms. That's because the BIP-BIN inputs have Zin=gigaohms.

The system uses the typical four wire measurement principle. Normally it's used to prevent the measuring wire resistance to affect the result, but contact resistance is taken into the account as well. Using AC doesn't change the idea. Read this: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/experiments/chpt-3/4-wire-resistance-measurement/

Your system should use 4 different contact probes (needles?) on the skin to be sure the voltage is measured from tissue, not from the current feeding probe. The probe placement geometry must be always the same for consistent results (=same geometric formation, same distances).

I guess that the interface IC can tell that there's overload i.e. too high resistance connected to the drive outputs. Too low contact resistance-that's non-existent. Zero ohms is optimal.

If it happens that you are trying to find the contact resistance to extract some extra information - like is the test object nervous - is a different thing. For example lie detection uses that idea.